# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, xampp, localhost

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it in C:\xampp\htdocs\OJT\assets\connection.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\OJT\assets\connection.php(7): mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'uipv2') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\OJT\index.php(2): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\OJT\assets\connection.php on line 7

Comment: You can use command line client to test the connection first with below information: 
localhost', 'root', '', 'uipv2'

Comment: I would rather propose to google the error message.

Comment: computer says "NO"...